# How to make a box using only the While loop?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

Ok, so i have a project to do, and I need some help with it. I can only use the While statements, (not for) and I need to create a box of asterisks, and so a user can input the width and the length of the box, how do I make the box? cause I got the top and bottom line done, but I do not know how to do the middle lines so theres a * on both sides and spaces in the middle of it. Here is what I have so far, be in mind this is only my 4th month coding in Java.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {
    private static int width, length = 0;
    //Program 2
    public static void input(){
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("What is the width? ");
        width = console.nextInt();
        System.out.print("What is the length? ");
        length = console.nextInt();
    }
    public static void topBottom(int width){
        while(width >= 1){
            System.out.print("x");
            width--;
        }
    }
    public static void length(int length){ //this is mainly where i need help
        int num = length - 2; //num is for the spaces in between the two * in the middle
        while(length >= 3){ //I have no idea how to create the box effect
            System.out.println("x");
            while(num >= 0){
                System.out.print(" ");
                num--;
            }
            length--;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        input();
        topBottom(width);
        System.out.println("");
        length(length);
        topBottom(width);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must do the same thing you're doing in `length()`, i.e. do a loop subtracting 2, but for each of the lines:

```
public static void width(int width){
    int num = width - 2;
    System.out.print("x");      // Print the leftmost 'x'
    while(num > 0){             // Repeat for each column
        System.out.print(" ");  // Print a space
        num--;
    }
    System.out.println("x"); // Print the rightmost 'x' and change line
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    input();
    topBottom(width);          // Print header
    System.out.println();
    int rows = length - 2;
    while (rows > 0) {         // Repeat for each of the rows, minus 2 (top and bottom)
        width(width);
        rows--;
    }
    topBottom(width);          // Print footer
    System.out.println();
}
```

You also had the width and length concepts mixed up.
That's assuming you always want to print a first and last row, i.e., it makes no sense to print a box smaller than 2x2.

Also, note there's no need to pass `width` and `length` around since it's already stored.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think i specified it clearly, i need to have blank spaces in the middle of the box, not just it being all one block of x's

Answer (score 0):

how do you plan on doing the length without knowing the width try this

```
 public static void length(int length,int width){ //this is mainly where i need help
    int num = length - 2; //num is for the spaces in between the two * in the middle
    int num2= width-2;

    while(num >= 0){ //I have no idea how to create the box effect
        System.out.print("x");
        while(num2 >= 0){
            System.out.print(" ");
            num2--;
        }
        System.out.print("x");
        System.out.println();

        num2=width-2;
        num--;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry to say, but I think this is missing somethings... it would run infinite loop.

Comment: @joejoethemonkey there's no infinite loop, `num` decrements in each iteration of the outer loop and `num2` in each iteration of the inner loop, the loops will be completed.